# what is the best way to remove no-unused-expressions from react js file

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslintrc

I am trying to get ride of this error `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`

I was able to do that by using this tag `/* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */` at the start of the file

but what if i have multiple files that is generating such issue can't i do it from the configuration file `.eslintrc.js` itself?

i tried to add this in the configuration file and remove the `/* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */` but that didn't work

```
const react = require('eslint-plugin-react');
const globals = require('globals');
 module.exports = {
      "root": true,
      "extends": [
         "eslint:recommended",
         "plugin:react/recommended"
      ],
     "overrides": [],
     "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
     "files": ['**/*.{js,jsx,mjs,cjs,ts,tsx}'],
     "plugins": [
       react
     ],
     "languageOptions": {
        "parserOptions": {
            "ecmaFeatures": {
               "jsx": true,
            },
        },
       "globals": {
          ...globals.browser,
       },
    },
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-expressions": "off" // i added this but didn't work
    }
  };
```

The structure of my root folder is

[image]

[image]

i also try to add this but also didn't work

```
 "overrides": [
{
    "files": ['**/*.{js,jsx,mjs,cjs,ts,tsx}'],
    "rules": {
            "no-unused-expressions": "off"
        }
}
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a new .eslintc configuration file in the same directory as your test files, configured to disable that rule. This allows you to use the default configuration for all other rules while ignoring that rule specifically only on files in that folder. ESLint calls this Configuration Cascading.

```
{
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-expressions": "off"
    }
}
```

Use the overrides key in your main .eslintrc file and it will disable rules for groups of files with matching patterns:

```
{
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": ["*.test.js", "*.spec.js"],
            "rules": {
                "no-unused-expressions": "off"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This also allows you to disable other rules which become troublesome in testing.

Comment: Can you please check my edited question as i tired that as well

Comment: i didn't add a configuration file in the same directory rather i added the override section as mentioned in my edit but didn't work